# Self Referencing, Inheriting Classes, how to overwrite common column values on JOIN with Doctrine2?

Tags: php, inheritance, orm, doctrine-orm, associations

Alright, so I've got a bit of a doozy here.

I'm using Symfony2, but more specifically the ORM, Doctrine2.  I have the following class written up as `ParameterType`:

```
<?php
namespace MSS\CMDBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 *  @ORM\Entity
 *  @ORM\Table(name="ParameterType")
 *  @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 *  @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 *  @ORM\DiscriminatorMap(
 *      {
 *          "integer" = "IntegerParameterType",
 *          "enumerated" = "EnumeratedParameterType"
 *      })
 */
class ParameterType {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $system;

}

?>
```

...and I have a class `IntegerParameterType` that extends ParameterType and is defined as follows:

```
<?php
namespace MSS\CMDBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 *  @ORM\Entity
 *  @ORM\Table(name="IntegerParameterType")
 */
class IntegerParameterType extends ParameterType {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $sizeInBits;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    protected $signed;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $units;

}

?>
```

...now every so often I'll be given a new `IntegerParameterType` that only has a name and a base type.  The base type is a string that references the name of another `IntegerParameterType` (something like "uchar" or "ushort").

What I want to do is input another field into `IntegerParameterType` labeled "baseType" and store the string in my database (MySQL).  However, when I want to use this object in my code I want the properties of that base `IntegerParameterType` (`IPT`) to come along with it (basically override the default values that would be initial stored in an `IPT` that only came with a name and baseType).

What I've tried so far is to attempt to make a self-referential property inside of `IntegerParameterType` like so:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="IntegerParameterType")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="baseType", referencedColumnName="name")
 */
protected $baseType;
```

However, this does not work and errors out with `General error: 1005 Can't create table... (errno: 150)`

How can I get this class to reference another `IntegerParameterType`, and upon a JOIN overwrite (if possible) the values from itself with the values from the other object?

Thanks in advance!